# Prevent a branch from pushing to a specific remote

Tags: git

So here's the deal. We have two branches in our project:

```
> git branch
> * master
>   development
```

We also have two remotes:

```
> git remote
> heroku_live
> heroku_dev
```

So, effectively each branch has it's own assigned remote. `master` branch pushes to `heroku_live` and `development` pushes to `heroku_dev`, this allows us to have a sandbox environment for development. We are aware that we can run the development branch on a local server however there are instances where we'd like to demonstrate functionality to customers off site, hence why we have a `heroku_dev`.

Now the problem here (or potential problem) is that someone might **accidently** push the development branch to the live server or vice versa. How can we prevent this from happening? Is there a way to restrict which remotes a branch can push to?

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
git checkout development
git branch --set-upstream-to heroku_dev
git checkout master
git branch --set-upstream-to heroku_live
git config push.default upstream
```

This would set `git push` to do what you want, that is to push the current branch to the defined remote branch, so you can use `git push` without any arguments, thus preventing mistakes. Of course, you need to do that once for every local copy of the project.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know heroku, but I guess you configured `heroku_live` to deploy the branch `master` and `heroku_dev` to deploy branch `development` right? So what is the big problem if someone pushes the development branch to branch `development` of remote `heroku_live`?

If it is a problem for you and you want to prevent this, you can simply add a `pre-receive` hook to both heroku remotes that does forbid to push to the respective other branch. But you cannot prevent someone from doing `git push heroko_live development:master` with a hook on server side I think. You could maybe add hooks to the local repositories that prevent this though, but those are local to the devs repo and can be ignored or disabled or not set up by the developer.

Answer (score 0):

Add appropriate git pre-receive [hooks](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks) in both remotes. 
Google that with  'filter on branch'  will surely find you an example.

Comment: That would not help, would it? If you push like `git push heroko_live development:master` you can still do so and the pre-receive hook cannot prevent this, as it does not know the local branch you are pushing from.

Comment: Sure. But I didn't get that would be a problem.